# Prove nth root of any positive real number exists for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, with Intermediate Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Need help with this particular question:

Use the intermediate value theorem to prove that for any $n\in  \mathbb{N}$ and
$y > 0$
there exists an nth root for $y$, that is, a real number $x$ so
that $x^n = y$.
This generalizes our earlier result that every positive real
number has a square root.

Comment: Do you have a proof that *every positive real number has a square root* handy? If so, try to mimic it.

Comment: If $y>1$ then $0<y<y^n$. If $y < 1$ then $0 < y < 1^n$.

Answer (score 1):

It may be proved using the least upper bound property of the reals. That is, the reals have the property that every non-empty subset which is upper bounded has the least upper bound in the reals.

Let the set $E$ be the subset of poitive reals, say $t$, such that $t^n<y$.
Then the above property guarantees that there exists the least upper bound of $E$, and it is not difficult to show that the $n$-th power of the least upper bound is indeed $y$.